# How to authenticate POST Azure API call?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-sql-database, azure-api-management

I want to perform this API call: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/2021-02-01-preview/databases/resume

However I can't seem to figure out how to authenticate myself. I'd prefer to use my AD account, as it is the server AD admin so it should have sufficient permissions.

As an alternative I've tried this approach: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#how-to-call-azure-rest-apis-with-postman

But the only web app I have does not have permissions for that.

Comment: Did you checked that your token has permission for that?  Additionally could you please first try with Microsoft Graph Explorer's to check if you  can execute this operation.

Comment: You can refer this link-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/apimanagementrest/azure-api-management-rest-api-authentication